# In SpriteKit, is it possible to add elements programmatically to the scene, so when .sks is opened, they display?

Tags: sprite-kit, scene, skscene

In SpriteKit, is it possible to add elements programmatically to the scene, so when .sks is opened, they display? Currently I have my `GameScene` (which extends `SKScene`) class that opens up already added elements in the scene editor, from the .sks file, using the UnarchiveFromFile method pattern. This method looks like this:

```
    @implementation SKScene (Unarchive)

+ (instancetype)unarchiveFromFile:(NSString *)file {
    /* Retrieve scene file path from the application bundle */
    NSString *nodePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:file ofType:@"sks"];
    /* Unarchive the file to an SKScene object */
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:nodePath
                                          options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe
                                            error:nil];
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *arch = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
    [arch setClass:self forClassName:@"SKScene"];
    SKScene *scene = [arch decodeObjectForKey:NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey];
    [arch finishDecoding];

    return scene;
}

@end
```

How can I do the opposite thing from the unarchiveFromFile, ie. to go from the code and add sprites to the .sks file. After that, the unarchiveFromFile would be triggered and the rest goes as it is right now. Any suggestions guys? Thanks.

Comment: it is unclear what yo are asking can you please provide more info

Comment: Ok, I will add more info in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my actual problem! - by just putting in a graph on the scene and getting it in the code. It is a NavigationGraph, and works fine. The programatic adding however didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want update your .sks file in code, even if you managed to work out how to do it. I think what you want to do is to add elements to the scene in `didMoveTo(view:)`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscene/1519607-didmove

> didMove(to:) Called immediately after a scene is presented by a view.
>
> Discussion This method is intended to be overridden in a subclass. You
>   can use this method to implement any custom behavior for your scene
>   when it is about to be presented by a view. For example, you might use0
>   this method to create the scene’s contents.

Here's an example to add a border:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
/* Setup your scene here */

//        drawBorder()
let border = drawSKShapeNode([CGPoint.zero,
    CGPoint(x: 0, y: frame.height),
    CGPoint(x: frame.width, y: frame.height),
    CGPoint(x: frame.width, y: 0)],
                             withWidth: 10,
                             inColour: SKColor.yellow,
                             called: "border")
border.zPosition = 200
addChild(border)
}

// Helper function to draw an SkShapeNode

    func drawSKShapeNode(_ withPoints: [CGPoint], withWidth width: CGFloat, inColour colour: SKColor, called name: String) -> SKShapeNode {

        var points = withPoints
        let shape = SKShapeNode(points: &points, count: points.count)
        shape.lineWidth = width
        shape.strokeColor = colour
        shape.name = name

        return shape 
}
```

Comment: Well, this is how I do it right now, but I really wanted to do this form my question, ie. to prepare the map of the level, and then to see it on the screen in Scene Editor, and then to add more elements to it manually on the Scene Editor.

Comment: I can understand why you'd want to do this. Placing and editing things in the Scene Editor, particularly if you want to be exacting, is a ***NIGHTMARE*** @VladimirDespotovic

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic It doesn't sound like this is how you do it at the moment - you never mentioned `didMoveTo()`. But what are you trying to achieve? What's the point in programatically adding things to the .sks file when you can just programmatically add things to the scene? OR are you talking about running a program (not an actual Sprite-Kit game) to build or update your .sks file before your then use it in the scene editor to place elements manually prior to using this .sks file in your game?

Comment: @Confused exactly my problem here. It's tough having to put blocks manually and to be exact all at the same time.

Comment: @SteveIves Imagine you want to eyeball a whole bunch of design stuff, within the context of an exactingly designed scene. But in order to build that exacting initial scene, to then do the manual placement, you first need to use the Scene Editor of SK/Xcode to place all the cookies. That is not fun. If there was a way to programmatically place all the cookie cutter details of a level, and then begin eyeballing and moving stuff around in the editor with all that stuff already in there (by code or from a spreadsheet) then that would be MUCH easier/funner.

Comment: That would be nice. But much more complex than just being able to import a plist of positions or a spreadsheet of them, or a csv of them... or for them to fix the funky handling of it so it's like using Photoshop or anything else that's not completely horrible for putting things in, selecting them and moving them around arbitrarily and exactly.

Comment: With all due respect to the Scene Kit team, the Sprite Kit editor isn't the worst editor in Xcode, just second worst. But that might only be by virtue of having one less dimension to mess up and mangle.

Comment: I’ll admit that I don’t have any problem laying things out in `didMoveTo` and then just adjusting my code if things don’t look right, but I can see where you’re coming from. Even a ‘snap to grid’ option would be welcome.